# Display image on UIImageView using Web server image

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiimageview, nsdata

I want to display an image on UIImageView calling **the Web server image**.
Because I want to replace and show it right away.

here's the code

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
webImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

The problem is...
The image is displayed well at first,
but if I replaced the image on the web server with another image.(The file name is the same, only the file is replaced) **It didn't change and still displayed the first image.**

Please help me...

Comment: Are you using NSURLSession? Check your cachePolicy. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957378/how-to-cache-using-nsurlsession-and-nsurlcache-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question seems flawed, i.e. you apparently do a network request in the UI thread. Such approach tends to make your application UI unresponsive. However, if we boil down the question to "**Why `NSData` returns outdated data for the same URL?**" then the answer is because it has internal caching. The caching logic could controlled either by the the response headers from the server (e.g. [Expires](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Expires)) or with [`NSDataReadingUncached`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatareadingoptions/nsdatareadinguncached) option (to suppress any caching logic):

```objc
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! 'NSDataReadingUncached' is not working... So I used SDWebImage lib.